# usage of exit command in Makefile causes compilation error

Tags: c++, makefile, rvds

I am using the status of "mycommand" as below in Makefile

```
EXIT=exit 1
mycommand || $(EXIT)
```

with the above usage in Makefile while compiling i'm getting an error in windows.

```
Application encountered an unexpected error.  Stopping.
```

did i need to update any environmental variables or any settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exit with an exit code of 1 that signals an error. You should do `exit 0` on success.

Comment: if mycommand executes properly then it returns success otherwise it exits with error.